# Read/Write NSSet/NSMutableSet to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, io

Is there any way of reading/writing NSSet/NSMutableSet to disk?

Or is there a category out there in the wild that enables it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array as an intermediary. Writing:

```
NSArray* temp = someSet.allObjects;
if (![temp writeToURL:someURL atomically:YES])
    /* handle error */;
```

Reading:

```
NSArray* temp = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
if (!temp)
    /* handle error */;
NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:temp];
```

Comment: I was avoiding this but looks like there's no other way. And this doesn't feel that bad.